# CMake not finding gfortran in docker

Tags: docker, cmake, gfortran

Trying to compile code in an ubuntu docker image, cmake is complaining that it cannot find a fortran compiler

Using this dockerfile to build an image

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest

USER root

# install git and gcc compilers
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -qq build-essential gfortran git cmake

# Create user "docker"
RUN useradd -m docker && \
    cp /root/.bashrc /home/docker/ && \
    mkdir /home/docker/data && \
    chown -R --from=root docker /home/docker

WORKDIR /home/docker/data
USER root
```

I am running `FC=gfortran cmake PATH_TO_CODE`, from within the container, and getting result:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindFORTRANCOMPILER.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "FORTRANCOMPILER", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FORTRANCOMPILER"
  with any of the following names:

    FORTRANCOMPILERConfig.cmake
    fortrancompiler-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "FORTRANCOMPILER" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "FORTRANCOMPILER_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "FORTRANCOMPILER" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:83 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "STREQUAL" "gfortran"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

The same works normally on the host linux system however.

Comment: Did you try installing `pkginfo`?

Comment: Run apt-get install python3-pkginfo to install pkginfo, and checked all packages again and still have same issue.

Comment: The error is **project-specific**. According to the error message, the project calls `find_package(FORTRANCOMPILER)` and most likely expects the file `FindFORTRANCOMPILER.cmake` to be found at some project-specific location. E.g. it could be an other repository, which should be cloned. Which project do you build?

Comment: Thanks: recloning the repo in its entirety fixed the issue